# Unable to set html table height and width with php variabile

Tags: php, html

I'm working on the PHP script below and I would like to set the td height and column by using a php variable, I'm unable to figure out how to do. Any tips and assistance to help me resolve it is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

$n = 5;
$table_height = 100;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Table is Ready</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <table>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++): ?>
            <tr>
                <?php for ($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++): ?>
                <td height="{$table_height}"; width = "{$n}"><?php print($i * $x) ?></td> 
                <?php endfor ?>   
                </tr>
            <?php endfor ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one thing, your variables are not inside a PHP block. For another, using a style attribute would be better than `height` and `width`, though it may not be as effective as you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<td height="{$table_height}";...>
```

To

```
<td height="<?= $table_height ?>px";...>
```

You'll probably need to do the same with cell width.  `{$var}` doesn't actually print a PHP value.  You need the php brackets `<?= ?>` to echo.